# Home Automation Sensor Circuit Unexpected State

Tags: circuit-design, sensor, home-automation

I embarked in a DIY project to replace a burnt home automation controller with a solution based on a Raspberry Pi using its GPIO inputs and outputs. I designed and built the electronics using breadboards and it's pretty much working now after several iterations. I still have a glitch that I haven't managed to understand and sort out and wondered if anybody could help me out to understand what could be the physical mechanism that is driving it and find a solution for it.

The problem arises only when the fire sensor is triggered, and the issue is that the associated led lights up as expected, but at the same time all the leds of the motion sensors light up as well and remain in that state indefinitely. The behavior is expected for the fire sensor as it is of a bistable type, but I don't know what drives the leds of the motion sensors to remain on indefinitely. The flood sensor doesn't light up, it's only the 6 motion sensors. The outputs in the raspberry side show the 7 sensors as active. The issue doesn't always occur, in some cases it works correctly and only the fire led lights up. It seems to occur most likely if several motion sensors have been triggered when the fire sensor is triggered, but not really sure. Once I cut the current from the fire sensor to ground via the transistor, everything returns to normal.

You can see the pictures and other info in the link https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=300969.

The fire sensor info is available in this link, I'm afraid it's only in Spanish: https://www.calytel.com/Files/110195/153493301422160.pdf

The motion sensors are Pyronix.

The latest schematic is:

[image]

I am trying to find a fix before I jump into designing the PCB, would really appreciate if anybody has any insight on what could be the cause/fix. Thanks!

**Edit:**

After further investigations I think I have found the issue. I took some readings in the comparator when the fire sensor was active and found that the input in the comparator was negative, around -0.7 V. The spec sheet of the comparator has the following maximum rating: VIN Input voltage -0.3 to +36 V. I read that Phase Reversal can occurr in some comparators, this seems to explain the behaviour I am encountering. I have seen that I have different voltage levels in the ground cabling of my breadboard. Not really sure what the cause is, could it be the lengths of cabling in my breadboard?

Now the question is how to solve the issue. As I am going to build a PCB, with proper ground plane design will I solve the issue? As it's the first time that I'm going to design a PCB, can you give me any advice on how I should do the PCB design to solve this problem?

Another question is if I should connect the earth cable to the ground input from the power supply. The previous controller I am replacing had connections to both earth and the negative port of the power supply. Any disadvantages on connecting the earth cable to the ground?

And one final question, in my design I have two grounds, one corresponding to the 15V power supply, which I plan to connect to earth unless there is any issue with that, and another one in the Raspberry Circuit side (plug is not earthed in this case). Can I put both ground circuits on the same layer of the PCB making use of a 2 layer PCB or should I put them in different layers, requiring a 4 layer PCB?

Thanks in advance for the help!

**Edit 2:**

In case somebody reads this post and encounters a similar issue, an update on the matter. I designed the PCB and it has been working flawlessly since July :-) The issue was definitely phase reversal due to the length of the cabling (primarily ground) in the breadboard, and it was resolved with the PCB.

Regarding the other matters, I did not connect the earth cable to ground. I left one part of the PCB for the 15V circuit, and another part for the Raspberry Pi circuit, no issue with having them in the same layer as they were physically separated.

Learnt a lot from this project, first PCB designed and fully working!

Comment: it seems to be ground shift from the choice ground paths as PIR sensors need very stable low noise input. To ensure this is the case, block Motion sensors to verify it is a conducted noise issue, then re-route cables to avoid sharing load currents directly from supply or some other stabilizer like LDO on Sensors.

Comment: But if blocking the sensors also stops the problem, it seems to be detecting LED heat. If instantly On then it is a conducted problem, but you didn’t say. So if on continuously with fire  LEDs then looks  like a radiated issue, thus orientation or proximity is undersireable..

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions @TonyStewartEE75. The 7 leds (fire sensor led and 6 motion sensor leds) stay on continuously, I suppose that if it had to do with the noise it would eventually go away when it stabilizes, but it is not the case. In my setup I have the 6 motion sensor leds contiguous, after that I have the flooding sensor led, and then the fire led, so I guess I have to discard also the radiated possibility, as the flooding sensor that is in between doesn't light up.